# Backup maintentce plan stopped working. Error -1073548784

Tags: sql-server-2014, maintenance-plan

Maintenance backup plan worked for a while. But a few weeks ago it stopped. I've noted it when I've run out of free space on a drive. So it creates a backup files, but stopped deleting outdated.

At first, I thought it was a permissions issue - but no. It still in place. New files created as intended. But an old is not deleting.

```
“Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [ReportServer] TO  DISK = N'E:\\Pro..." failed with the following error: 
"Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (1:1886), database ID 12.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.”
```

[image]

What could be the issue?